# Python array search

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

i am student of class 11,below question is for 20 point.can some one please help me to resolve it

question

```
world =[{"country":"India","state":"MH,Punjab,JH,UK,MP","area":"2344535"}]
```

find when user enter some state name print its country name. i have multiple row with different country and state name

i have try this below but unable to get any output can someone please solve it but get no output

```
for i in world:
    if (i['state']=='Punjab'):
        print(i['country'])
```

Comment: The first code sample setting `world` is syntactically incorrect. Is this really from the original question?

Comment: yes I also get SyntaxError: invalid syntax when trying to use your code

Comment: `'MH''Punjab''JH''UK''MP'` is one string, `'MHPunjabJHUKMP'`

Comment: i have just type here the quetion may be i type mistake but yes in  state is in one string

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the input is in string `state`, since `state` is a single string and you were comparing `'Punjab'=='MHPunjabJHUKMP'` which is false, you can try to use [in](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-check-if-python-string-contains-another-string):

```
world =[{'country':'India','state':'MHPunjabJHUKMP','area':'2344535'},
{'country':'Pakistan','state':'islamabadPunjabkarachisindhBalochistan','area':'2124765'} ,
{'country':'USA','state':'MINYrhode','area':'21232249885'},
{'country':'China','state':'MacauBengbuFuyang','area':'2872324753235'}
]
for i in world:
    if ('Punjab' in i['state']):
        print(i['country'])
```

And if you want to compare every case of input, e.g `'Punjab','punjab','PUNJAB'`, you should cast then into the same case (lower or upper) and then compare them, by changing your condition to `if ('punjab'.lower() in i['state'].lower()):`

Comment: world =[{"country":"India","state":"MH,Punjab,JH,UK,MP","area":"2344535"}] can you see this query i have multiple row in world

Comment: Yeah, and that´s why you use the for loop, to iterate over the multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get the list or can print the elements

```
[i['country'] for i in world if "Punjab" in i["state"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this a list comprehension with unpacking the list into a print statement

```
world =[{"country":"India","state":"MH,Punjab,JH,UK,MP","area":"2344535"}]
print(*[i['country'] for i in world if i["state"].count("Punjab") > 0])
```

This will output

```
India
```